# Strategies to get more performance in a specific scenario

Tags: performance, many-to-many

#### Introduction

Hi Guys, my name's Joao, i'm currently working as backend and that's my first post. 
I'll appreciate any help!

My team are working on a new feature. During the process of development we face a doubt about database performance, and so far we have some divided opinions... so here i'm rs

#### Tabble structure

For the example, a many-to-many relationship:

[image]

#### The scenario

Considering tables above, our API must serve an POST endpoint that, receive a **Domain ID** as a path variable and a json containing a list of **Users Id**, something like that:

```
Path : /domain/1

Body Json : 
    {
      "users":[
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
```

With that list we must persist on the many-to-many **domain_users** that relationship between users and domains. Resume, in one endpoint we must manager the many-to-many table registers.

#### The question

We made this in two different ways, i'm here to ask your opinion what's the more efficiently, performatic etc.. by the database side, thinking bout I/O

**Strategie A (Clean and Insert)**
First we delete ALL the registers in **domain_users** where the field **domain_id** is equals the **Domain ID** of the request, and then we insert in **domain_users** all users of the request list for that domain. Considering the above Json example, in this strategie we'll perform one delete and one insert with two registers on the table **domain_users**.

**Strategie B (Logical relationship)**
First we compare the list of users that came with the request and the list of users that are already linked for that **Domain ID**, by a select on the **domain_users** where the field **domain_id** is equals the **Domain ID** of the request, so we execute these conditionals:
1 - There's a user that came in the Json Request list and aren't present in database list? Insert that!
2 - There's a user that are present in the database list and aren't present in the Json Request ? Delete that!
3 - There's a user that are present in both list (database and Json Request) ? Do nothing.
In this strategie, the number of operations performed on the database depends of registers already present on the **domain_users** many-to-many table.

Which of the two strategies should we follow, thinking about better performance of database?

**Obs** : Our backend are in Java and the database we are working now is a PostgreSQL version 12

Comment: Depends on how many records we're talking about. But deleting all and inserting all certainly seems a lot easier (and less code = less bugs). But watch out for foreign key dependencies -- if there are any (others) that will prevent you from deleting.

Comment: Hi Colin, tks for reply. About the records, probably a lot of them(0-200, 0-400, depends the Domain) the example i provided it's a real scenario here. I agree with u that deleting and inserting is a easy way, and less chances to Bug, but i still thinking if deleting and inserting around 200, 300 records per call on that endpoint wouldn't 'punch' too much the database... For be honest, all devs on the Team prefer these Strategie A, less work rs However, performance must be around us in this project... About that average of records I said, u still think a good way that strategie?